# Receive response when using PostMessage for Youtube Iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, cross-domain, youtube-javascript-api

I am building a chrome extension that plays a youtube video in the background page with controls for it in an injected content script.
I can use play/pause quite effectively using this code:

iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
            "event": "command",
            "func": func,
            "args": args || [],
            "id": frame_id
        }), "*");

My question is how would I receive a response if I were to pass in say getVolume or something similar as my function?
Incidentally, is there a better way to do this? 
Basically I wish for a video to be played in my extension. I could put the video in my content script but then every time a user changes/refreshes a page, the iframe for the video would also be refreshed. 
Is there a way to display a video in a content script that doesn't refresh with pages or do I have to do it an app?

Thanks in advance,
Rohan

Comment: I'm now looking for the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073962/youtube-player-api-retrieving-a-reference-to-an-existing-player/17076473?noredirect=1#17076473