# YouTube Player API: retrieving a reference to an existing player

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm developping a Google Chrome extension, using content script. I want to interact with pages embedding a YouTube video player. I have include the `www-widgetapi-vfljlXsRD.js` as a JavaScript file, and YouTube namespace is correctly initialize inside the extension sandbox.

I'm trying to retrieve a reference to an existing iFrame player. To achieve that, I tried this:

```
var ytplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer'); 
ytplayer.pauseVideo();
```

where `div#ytplayer`is the iFrame embedding the actual player.

I'm getting this error, telling that the method does not exist:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'pauseVideo'

What is the correct way to retrieve a reference to an existing player?

Comment: If you only want to pause/play a video, have a look at the first link at the right of this question (below the "Related" header).

Comment: I want to get the current time of the video actually. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I was using YouTube player API before and it was working properly. Today I have issues like you, and I did not change anything in my code. It might mean that the `www-widgetapi-vfljlXsRD.js` has been changed and encounters bugs... I cannot help any further.

Comment: The issue is now solved but I still can't get a reference to an existing player. Do you manage to do that on your side?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found my way to talk to an existing player. I have not actually managed to get a working reference to it.

I was inspired by the amazing work of Rob (cf. [YouTube iframe API: how do I control a iframe player that's already in the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html?rq=1)), I remarked that the Youtube player is sending message to the main window, like this:

`{"event":"infoDelivery","info":{"currentTime":3.3950459957122803,"videoBytesLoaded":244,"videoLoadedFraction":0.24482703466872344},"id":1}`

You can observe it by listening to the "message" event `window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {console.log(event.data)}, false);` in a window containing a playing player.

This `infoDelivery` event contains the current player's time and is sent while the video is playing. Listening to this event I am now able to know the current player time.

I have not found a proper solution so far so this one will make the job for the moment.

Comment: unfortunately not working for me 10 years later. My player is located within another iframe which I can't change and there is absolutely no possible way to interact with the player. `postMessage` probably works but for anything else, no event can be listened to and no message appears anywhere. The API does not work inside the iframe and cannot point into the iframe from outside. I just wanted to loop the a video over a specific time span but after trying everything, I will give up on that and will restrict YouTube playback features in comparison to when a direct video link is used.