# YouTube iframe_api Google example does not work anymore

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I am trying the example in [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and it does not work in any browser. I'm not completely sure, but I believe it worked some days ago. Is it possible they changed
something in http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api?

Internet Explorer gives:

> Array.prototype.forEach: 'this' is null or undefined

[Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) gives several:

> 1. Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin http://mylocalmachine.com:55495. www-widgetapi-vfljlXsRD.js:22
> 2. Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://mylocalmachine.com:55495". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
> 3. Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined www-widgetapi-vfljlXsRD.js:5
> 4. Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'playVideo'

Comment: well I tried their live demo in https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo and it does not work as well.

Unbelivable. Does this happen often?

Comment: We started seeing an issue with the iframe api about 18 hours ago. The YT.Player constructor is creating a player object that doesn't have all the methods it is supposed to have.  For example, no getPlayerState.

Answer (score 2):

I think Google changed the YouTube player API in some way that it is completely bogus. I was using it until today with no problems, and I have the same issues now. A recent Stack Overflow post, [an answer to *YouTube Player API: retrieving a reference to an existing player*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073962/youtube-player-api-retrieving-a-reference-to-an-existing-player/17076473#17076473), also complains about this.

Comment: Also having the same issue with code that worked flawlessly before...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like YouTube is aware of the problem. From https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4706:

> The engineering team has identified an issue that is preventing the
>   iframe API from functioning at the moment. They have traced the root
>   cause to a disruption caused by an ongoing server-side push, and once
>   that push is fully complete, the JavaScript errors should completely
>   subside. It will likely be several more hours before the push is
>   complete, unfortunately.
>
> This is not expected to be a regular occurrence, and we apologize for
>   the inconvenience caused by this outage.

Based on their message, it sounds like it should be back to functioning as soon as possible.