# How do I get the reference to an existing YouTube player?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I have a few questions on what happens when I embed a YouTube video using source code like above. The code should generate a YouTube Player object that processes the video the way users like. When I generate a Youtube Player by myself using Youtube Player API(instead of using the embed code), I can call call functions on it.

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

//player.playVideo(); will play the video.
```

My question is, how do I control the player object generated by the embed code? To put it in another way, from page http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7lc1UVf-VE, how do I play the video by calling `SOMEPlayer.playVideo()`? When you go to the url, `ytplayer` object is available, but it doesn't seem to contain the necessary functions.

This question might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073962/youtube-player-api-retrieving-a-reference-to-an-existing-player).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This can be done like the following.

Given a general YouTube embed source code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

a. Add a `enablejsapi` query param and set it to 1 in the src URL

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

b. Give it a unique id

```
<iframe id="youtube-video" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

c. Load YouTube iFrame API

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

d. Create a player that references the existing iFrame

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('youtube-video', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady() {
  console.log("hey Im ready");
  //do whatever you want here. Like, player.playVideo();

}

function onPlayerStateChange() {
  console.log("my state changed");
}
```

Comment: Floradu88 http://jsfiddle.net/bf7zQ/1/ It actually does nothing in `onPlayerStateChange()` and `onPlayerReady()`; Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @spideep This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/bf7zQ/2/ You have to pass `?enablejsapi=1` and you have to use `https://`.

Comment: it seems that both urls have to be httpS

Comment: @Ads I believe that rather both protocols need to match. So either `http` or `https`

Comment: This isn't working for me. I'm getting an error (index):1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().
Promise (async)
(anonymous) @ scripts.js:20
dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.js:5226
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.js:4878
scroll (async)
d.getScrollTop @ skrollr.min.js:2
Aa @ skrollr.min.js:2
d.refresh @ skrollr.min.js:2
d @ skrollr.min.js:2
init @ skrollr.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ (index):493
cast_sender.js:67 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'PresentationRequest': Presentation of an insecure document [cast:233637DE?

Comment: FYI: for this to work your Youtube API event callbacks cannot be nested inside another function scope.

Answer (score 41):

```
var player = YT.get('id-of-youtube-iframe');
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: Lifesaver, thank you.
@Aziz, this is how you can use the YouTube API to get a reference to a player based on its element id.

Answer (score 6):

Maximus S gave a perfectly correct answer. The official [YouTube IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)
 docs suggest initialising the player through a unique id of an iframe with the video as `var yPlayer = new YT.Player('unique-id');`.

For the future readers of this question looking for a way to generate a YouTube Player from a reference to an iframe element without id (as myself), it is possible to do so by running `var yPlayer = new YT.Player(iframeElement);` if you add `type="text/html"` attribute to the iframe element and set `enablejsapi=1` parameter in the `src` attribute:

`<iframe type="text/html" height="360" width="640" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jNQXAC9IVRw?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>`

[Full snippet](http://jsbin.com/hifuhahone/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

A great way to do this without loading the IFrame API in the parent window is to grab the object from the IFrame

```
var ytplayer_window = document.getElementById("playerIFrame").contentWindow;
var player = ytplayer_window.yt.player.getPlayerByElement(ytplayer_window.player);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. What is `ytplayer_window.player` ?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is almost right.
You have to place "enablejsapi=1" on the iframe src.
Something like:

```
<iframe id="youtube-video" width="560" height="315" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" 
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: where is the docs on this variation/best practice.would be great just to clarify for the best practice. thanks