# Youtube API Set current time

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

I am currently using the You-Tube API for a project of mine.
The way I use it is the following:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
var alternatePlayer;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });

}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

It all works well, but for my project I need to be able to control the current time that the video is playing.
I have searched the You-Tube API notes and data but could not find a paramter nor a function that enables me to set the current time of the video (There is a GET for the current time but not a set).
There is a parameter `startseconds` that when mentioned in the youtube creation (I mean near the parameters height,width,videoId) can control what second the video starts from. This does not fit my needs because I need to change the current time of the SAME video and not load another one. Is there any way around this? Am I missing this set function? Must I recall the same videoId with the `startseconds`?
Thanks very much in advance for any light on that matter.

---

EDIT:
Okay, I have found the solution in some weird way. For some reason I don't see it mentioned on the You-Tube API.

```
player.seekTo(55,true);
```

This code will change the you-tube player to 55 seconds, which is a SET for the current time.
Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: Don't know the API exactly. Take a further look in the Open Source Javascript Librarys, that offer youtube support. (Sliders etc). My guess quick and dirty is to reload the frame with changed startseconds parameter, but is not nice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have searched but without any luck so far..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look into the following documents:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

First you need a JS reference to the `Player` object. For a quick start, please take a look at the following Question:

- [How do I get the reference to an existing YouTube player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603618/how-do-i-get-the-reference-to-an-existing-youtube-player)

With this reference you can do:

```
player.seekTo(42); //Go to 42 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I luckily found the solution before you. Accepted your answer!

Comment: Yeah, have seen it :) Started to find solution when you written last comment. Anyway, i would need this on my own in a short while :D