# How can I play/pause youtube player on its native site itself using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, youtube, firefox-addon

I am creating a chrome extension that automatically pauses the youtube video when I switch to another tab if the tab I am switching to is also youtube playing another video. I am looking for ways to have at least play/pause control over the native youtube player. All I could find on the internet after desperately searching is related to youtube iframe or embedding, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603618/how-do-i-get-the-reference-to-an-existing-youtube-player).

Is there any way I can achieve this by having direct control over the youtube player object or some other html5 browser features with javascript?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple on youtube video page.

> Try this simple js code:

```
var video = document.querySelector("video");
if (video.paused){video.play();} else {video.pause();}
```

But for embedded Youtube videos you may want to review through the Youtube [JavaScript API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) docs. Read this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15165166/1225070

For html5 Videos.

> Try this:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function playVid() {
    vid.play();
}

function pauseVid() {
    vid.pause();
}
```

Comment: The js code works and that's exactly what I wanted. I just couldn't get it since yesterday. Thank you very much, Sir.

Comment: Just did. But I can't upvote because of lack of reputation points. This is my first question on stackoverflow :) Thank you.

Comment: Great, and its fine!

Comment: @elegant-user is there somewhere you can see how to perform other functions on the youtube page itself? Such as playing the next or previous video?